# Flash Actionscript : Flash swf not loading from global servers

Tags: flash-cs5

I have written a simple program in actionscript that displays a line.
Here is the AS code

```
import flash.display.Graphics;
var g:Graphics=graphics;
 g.lineStyle(1,0,100);
 g.lineTo(100,100);
```

I published this code in flash CS5 and received corresponding SWF and HTML file.

When I upload these files to a local server then the swf file is loaded properly and the line is displayed.
But when I uploaded it to any of the global servers like goDaddy the flash stopped working. Nothing was displayed on the screen. 
On right clicking the flash panel it showed a message "movie not loaded".

And the strange fact is that its not happening on all systems. On some computers this flash is working fine.

Any idea what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the exact file name in your invoking HTML even for lowercases an uppercases? In Windows and Macintosh desktop computers or Windows Servers these differences are not important, but on linux servers, files like MYFILE.SWF are not the same than myfile.swf or MyFile.swf